# Virtualbox Install 64 bit Windows 10

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, 64-bit, windows-10

Every time i try to install Ubuntu there is no option for Windows 10 64 bit.  Only 32 bit.
1 - do I have to have a USB drive to install?  Can't I install to the VDI partition i just created?
2 - When trying to install using Windows 10 32 bit I get the following message:
"This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot, please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU"

My system:
Windows 10 Home version 10.0.14393
x64 based PC
Processor - Intel Core i3-6100U CPU @ 2.30 GHz, 2304MHz, 2 cores, 4 logical processors
Ram 6 GB

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Respectfully,
Trick

Comment: Are you going to install Ubuntu in a virtual box in windows?

Comment: The op states that his computer motherboard is x64 based that means that it is 64bit..

Answer (score 2):

Your question is confusing.. But regardless, if you're trying to install a 64 bit operating system onto a 32 bit machine, it's not going to work. 
Either install an OS with a 32 bit kernel, or upgrade to a 64 bit CPU. 
If virtual box is only showing 32 bit operating systems make sure that your Host OS is 64 bits, 
Intel Virtualization Technology and VT-d are both enabled in the BIOS, and the Hyper-V platform is disabled in your Windows Feature list.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run 64 bit guest OSes in VirtualBox, you must have a 64-bit capable processor with virtualization acceleration features. That's called VT-x for Intel or AMD-V for AMD.  You can check your exact CPU model on the Intel or AMD spec sites to see.  (Note it's OK to be running a 32-bit kernel, the processor just has to be capable.)

If the processor is capable and 64-bit OS types aren't shown, either the virtualization acceleration is disabled by a BIOS option -- go into BIOS setup to change it -- or some other virtualization package such as KVM is installed and has seized the virtualization hardware -- uninstall it.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a little searching I see that Windows 10 Home version 10.0.14393 comes in 32bit and 64bit. if your processor is x64 based as you say, you should be able to install a 64bit Windows 10. If you are trying to install in VBox make sure that you have "Windows 10 (64-bit) checked.

If you want to overwrite Windows on your computer with Ubuntu 64bit, then using a Live USB for installing is considered the best option. Mkusb makes a fine Ubuntu USB installer.

Answer (score 0):

I have 64bit windows 10 installed on my host system with an intel 64bit dual core processor.  I cant find a 64bit Ubuntu ISO, only a 32bit ISO.  I'll check to see that virtualization is on in the BIOS.  But from what you have said my 64bit windows 10 host should be able to run a 32bit Ubuntu through vbox.  Is that a correct statement.  The error message baffles me as it says it needs a 64bit environment, which it has.  so why that error message?  And why am I not seeing the new VDI partition so I can select it as the install location?  Sorry if these question seem elementary to you, but my last Linux install was a 32bit install on windows 7.  it was much more straight forward.  This install seems to have a mismatch between the actual hardware vs what the install software is identifying.  Should I be installing a 64bit Ubuntu ISO?  If so where do I find one?